# How to generate all directed permutations of an undirected graph?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am looking for a way to generate *all* possible directed graphs from an undirected template. For example, given this graph "template":

[image: Undirected template graph. A triangle missing an edge]

I want to generate all six of these directed versions:

[image: All versions of the graph with directed edges]

In other words, for each edge in the template, choose LEFT, RIGHT, or BOTH direction for the resulting edge.

There is a huge number of outputs for even a small graph, because there are 3^E valid permutations (where E is the number of edges in the template graph), but many of them are duplicates (specifically, they are automorphic to another output). Take these two, for example:

[image: Two isomorphic options]

I only need one.

---

I'm curious first: **Is there is a term for this operation?** This must be a formal and well-understood process already?

And second, **is there a more efficient algorithm to produce this list?** My current code (Python, NetworkX, though that's not important for the question) looks like this, which has two things I don't like:

1. I generate all permutations even if they are isomorphic to a previous graph
2. I check isomorphism at the end, so it adds additional computational cost

```
Results := Empty List
T := The Template (Undirected Graph)

For i in range(3^E):
    Create an empty directed graph G
    convert i to trinary
    For each nth edge in T:
        If the nth digit of i in trinary is 1:
            Add the edge to G as (A, B)
        If the nth digit of i in trinary is 2:
            Add the edge to G as (B, A)
        If the nth digit of i in trinary is 0:
            Add the reversed AND forward edges to G
   
    For every graph in Results:
        If G is isomorphic to Results, STOP
    Add G to Results
```

Comment: I think the computational run time and memory required warrants the question: do you really need all graphs or do you just need a representative sample of graphs? I think any exact solution will be brutal but sampling random adjacency matrices that satisfy the constraints given by the undirected graph would be quite easy

Comment: @PaulBrodersen — you make an excellent point. Unfortunately for this particular use-case I need an exhaustive list!

Comment: How many edges are in the undirected graph?

Comment: I'd say small graphs — anything larger than a 6 or 7 node graph quickly gets into the realm of completely computationally-infeasible parameter spaces.

Comment: This [pdf](https://www.weizmann.ac.il/mcb/UriAlon/sites/mcb.UriAlon/files/uploads/NetworkMotifsSW/mfinder/motifdictionary.pdf) may be of use in testing any implementation. It lists all possible directed graphs with 3 or 4 nodes. The document is from Uri Alon's lab. Since I suppose they automatically computed these graphs, he may have some guidance on how to tackle the problem. Code would probably be in C though. I had a brief email exchange with him a while back -- seemed like a nice guy.

Comment: More generally, anyone working on network motif analysis should have run into this problem at some point. Might be worth having a look around in that part of the literature.